# Endpoint specified in @RepositoryRestResource is not present when running the Springboot App

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm learning Springboot and was following the tutorial for connecting to MongoDB.

In order to create the endpoint, I've used  `@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")`

but the endpoint is not present, giving 404. But other endpoints are working as expected

Here;s the project Information

Controller Class

```
package com.play.reminder.Reminder;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

@RestController
public class StarController {

    private final AtomicInteger id =new AtomicInteger();
    private final String template = "Hello %s";

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "Hello, Welcome to Home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name){
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

    @GetMapping("/greetings")
    public Greetings greetings(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name){
        return new Greetings(id.getAndIncrement(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Application class

```
package com.play.reminder.Reminder;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.JSONPObject;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.JSONWrappedObject;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ReminderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReminderApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

MongoRepository class

```
package com.play.reminder.Reminder;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import java.util.List;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

Person class

```
package com.play.reminder.Reminder;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Person {

    @Id private String Id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.play.reminder'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:4.1.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:3.1.0'


}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Please do let me know if I'm missing something.

Here;s the link which I followed for tutorial
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/